# wordpress header image based on date

Tags: php, wordpress, header

Im not great at PHP but I typed up the following code to change the header image based on the date array I have set.

Im wondering if the code looks alright and will function as intended or if iv missed something in my coding.

```
    $hollidayevents = array(
  array(
   'image' => 'wp-content/uploads/1.png',
   'start' => '01-02',
   'end' => '02-02'
  ),
  array(
   'image' => 'wp-content/uploads/2.png',
   'start' => '03-02',
   'end' => '04-02'
  )
);
    
foreach($hollidayevents as $myevent) {
  if(date('d-m') >= $myevent['start'] && date('d-m') <= $myevent['end']) {
    echo "<img src='".$myevent['image']."'>";
  }
  else { echo "<img src='wp-content/uploads/default header image'>";}
}
```

Comment: you are comparing two strings like this: `'17-11' >= '01-02'` which is not what you want, only date formatted to YYYY-MM-DD works by comparing as strings, otherwise you have to convert the dates to DateTime or timestamp

Comment: ok, I was really looking only to do month and day but I went back to d-m-y format

Comment: well the year can be ommited in your case, but the order and double digits are important for string comparation, if you wanna keep it simple just use the `date('m-d')` and edit 'start' and 'end' accordingly

Comment: ok thats somewhat working but I think the foreach if else isnt working, instead of showing just one image the 'else' statement is showing for each month its not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare the dates as string with 'd-m' format the result is based on the day and only if days are same then it comes to compare months too.

For example imagine this: `'20-10' > '01-11'`, both are with format you used `'d-m'` what is the result ? First is higher then second so the result is true, even tho you would expect the opposite. Thats because only first character gets compared.

```
$hollidayevents = array(
  array(
   'image' => 'wp-content/uploads/1.png',
   'start' => '02-01', // <- m-d format
   'end' => '02-02' // <- m-d format
  ),
  array(
   'image' => 'wp-content/uploads/2.png',
   'start' => '02-03', // <- m-d format
   'end' => '02-04' // <- m-d format
  )
);

$eventFound = false;
foreach($hollidayevents as $myevent) {
  if(date('m-d') >= $myevent['start'] && date('m-d') <= $myevent['end']) {
    echo "<img src='".$myevent['image']."'>";
    $eventFound = true;
    break;
  }
}
if(!$eventFound){
    echo "<img src='wp-content/uploads/default header image'>";
}
```

Comment: that works awesome, thanks so much for your help